# Why does my server work well with postman but does not work well with my frontend?

Tags: express, next.js, multer

Here is my server:

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

//----------------------------------------
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    const fileType = file.fieldname === "coverImage" ? "images" : "books";
    cb(null, fileType); // Specify the destination directory based on file type
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname); // Use the original file name
  },
});

const validateFileTypes = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.fieldname === "book" && !file.originalname.endsWith(".pdf")) {
    return cb(new Error('Only PDF files are allowed for the "book" field'));
  }

  if (file.fieldname === "coverImage" && !file.mimetype.startsWith("image/")) {
    return cb(
      new Error('Only image files are allowed for the "bookCover" field')
    );
  }

  // Accept the file
  cb(null, true);
};
app.use(
  multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter: validateFileTypes }).fields([
    { name: "book", maxCount: 1 }, // 'images' field can have up to two files
    { name: "coverImage", maxCount: 1 }, // 'documents' field can have up to three files
  ])
);

//--------------------------------------

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ status: "success", msg: "It's working!" });
});

// app.post("/upload", (req, res, next)=>{

//   console.log(req.files);
//   console.log(req.body);
//   res.status(200).json({msg: "Files Uploaded Successfully!"});

// })

app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
  // res.status(400).json({error: `Can't find the root you are looking for my love: ${req.url}`})
  const err = new Error(`Can't find the root ${req.url} my love`);
  err.status = "fail";
  err.statusCode = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  err.status = err.status || "error";
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;

  res.status(err.statusCode).json({ status: err.status, message: err.message });

  next();
});

app.listen(4000);
```

and here is my frontend:

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react"

export default function TestPage(){
    const [messageState, setMessageState] = useState({});

    const bookRef = useRef();
    const coverImageRef = useRef();

    
    const submitHandler = (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        const fileData = new FormData();
        fileData.append('book', bookRef.current.files[0]);
        fileData.append('coverImage', coverImageRef.current.files[0]);
        sendFile(fileData);
    }

    const sendFile= async (fileData) => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/", {
            method: "POST",
            body: fileData,
          });
      
          if (!response.ok) {
            // If the response status is not OK, throw an error
            const errorResponse = await response.json();
            const errorMessage = errorResponse.message || "Server error occurred";
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}. Error message: ${errorMessage}`);
          }
      
          const responseData = await response.json();
          setMessageState(responseData);
          // Handle success here if needed
        } catch (error) {
          // Handle any errors that occurred during the fetch
          setMessageState(error.message);
          // Display the server-provided error message to the user or perform additional actions
        //   alert(`Server Error: ${error.message}`);
        }
      };
      
      

    return (
        <>
        
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>

                <input type="file" ref={bookRef} />
                <input type="file" ref={coverImageRef} />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <h1>Message: {JSON.stringify(messageState)}</h1>
            {/* {messageState.map(item => <h1 key={item}>{item}</h1>)} */}
        </>
    )
}
```

This server is working well when I supply a pdf and an image file. But, when I supply some different file types, **I get an error response by the server sometimes and sometimes no response. **

Also,** this server is working perfectly fine when I am using postman.**